# WSO2 DSS issue when selecting Timestamps from Database

Tags: database, cassandra, timestamp, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I've an issue defining a query to get some data out of Cassandra in WSO2 DSS. The query (and the operation) itself is working but my problem is when I try to get a timestamp as a result. 
I only get the date and the timezone (2017-01-11+0100) the time part is missing. I guess that this is somehow related on the mapping to dateTime xsdType that is not working correctly.
Did you already face this issue, and do you have a solution to get the timestamp?

Here is a query sample

```
<query id="getDataQuery" useConfig="CassandraDB">
    <expression>SELECT ts,value FROM keyspace.ts_tp WHERE name = :name</expression>
    <result element="result" rowName="data">
        <element column="ts" name="ts" xsdType="dateTime"/>
        <element column="value" name="value" xsdType="decimal"/>
    </result>
    <param name="name" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING"/>
</query>
```

Thanks

Comment: A 'painful' option would be to deal with unix timestamp and then perform the conversion in the ESB by changing the query to `SELECT unixTimestampOf(minTimeuuid(ts)) as ts,value FROM keyspace.ts_tp WHERE name = :name` but I cannot imagine that there is no more straightforward solution to this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue in dss dateTime mapping, I opened a [Jira ticket @wso2](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DS-1266) to be sure. In order to make my call return the right values I made the following (Warning painful solution :))

The query returns now the unix Timestamp in ms

```
<query id="getDataQuery" useConfig="CassandraDB">
    <expression>SELECT unixTimestampOf(minTimeuuid(ts)) as dt,value FROM keyspace.ts_tp WHERE source = :source and name = :name and bucket = :bucket and ts &gt;= :tsFrom and ts &lt;= :tsTo</expression>
    <result element="result" rowName="data">
        <element column="dt" name="ts" xsdType="int"/>
        <element column="value" name="value" xsdType="decimal"/>
    </result>
    <param name="source" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING"/>
    <param name="name" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING"/>
    <param name="bucket" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
    <param name="tsFrom" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="TIMESTAMP"/>
    <param name="tsTo" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="TIMESTAMP"/>
</query>
```

Once I get the result I apply an XSL transformation to compute the dates

```
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xsl soapenv" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dt">
      <xsl:element name="ts">
         <xsl:value-of select='xs:dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00") + . * xs:dayTimeDuration("PT0.001S")'/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It needs to be tested with different time zones, and day light savings but it seems to be a working hack, waiting for the official fix.